# Change wallpaper of not-yet-attached monitor

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-background

In a couple of days I am going to give a presentation at a conference. For that I am going to plug a projector into my laptop. I forgot to change the wallpaper for the external monitor while at home. Since it is some fantasy/sci-fi themed wallpaper, I would like to change it to something more professional/neutral (just a simple color or such) before the presentation, but I do not have a monitor at my disposal in the hotel I am staying in. How can I change the background for all screens - the one of my laptop and the one that would be attached if I had one?

I am using Kubuntu 14.4 with KDE 4.13.3.